# win xp - change permissions and not require a restart?

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, network-shares, file-sharing

In Win XP, is it possible to change permissions on a network share, and not require a restart?

I don't mean, a case where one doesn't need a restart, though if there are cases where one does and cases where one doesn't , then that's interesting to know which.. But i'd rather a way where whatever the change in permissions, no restart is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing NTFS or share permissions on XP should generally not prompt for a restart. The only exception I can think of is due to a service being stopped.(unless I'm misunderstanding the question)

Comment: even if it doesn't prompt for a restart, it might require one. some changes do. How about the following A)Changing between SFS and AFS B)enabling or disabling Guest.    C)changing any permission on a file share.  Do none of these require a restart?

Comment: @barlop None of these require a restart.

Comment: @Sathya  I have had a problem though recently where it wouldn't accept my user/pass. I could access one share but not my admin share. I  might've then changed permissions a bit. Still didn't work. I restarted both computers, then it was fine. I thought that'd suggest that the restart fixed it.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304040 has an outline of what you can do with file sharing on XP. None of which require a restart. I can tell you changing permissions on a file share do not require a restart.

Comment: The functions I describe are not available in XP? Which functions do you mean?

Comment: I was under the Impression NFS shares could only be setup on server versions of windows but after double checking I was wrong.